# Google Apps Script - reject form submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-forms

My requirement is to validate the some of the form fields against some data upon form submission.  If the data doesnt match up, I wanted to reject the form submission and display an error.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: This question would be better for the [Web Apps Site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or the [Google Docs Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/docs)  Apps Script is server side code and can not validate Google Forms user input before the Form is submitted.  User input can be validated, and display an error to the user, but it's not with Apps Script.  There is no coding involved.  Therefore, this is not a programming question.

Comment: I'm asking on ways to do this via Google Apps Script (which involves coding ofcourse...) And I'm referring to server side validation, that's why I said "validate some of the form fields against some data UPON FORM SUBMISSION".  I didn't say client side validation...

Answer (score 0):

This is a built in feature for Google Forms:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en